# ListView ou GridView em Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou estudando sobre *Windows Forms Aplication*. Fiz um [tutorial](https://programandodotnet.wordpress.com/tag/consultorio/) em que se usa o ListView para mostrar os dados de uma pesquisa de acordo com os parâmetros passados.

Mas notei que também tem o GridView para usarmos na toolbox. E [neste outro tutorial](https://programandodotnet.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/exibicao-mestre-detalhe-de-registros-parte-1/), usa-se o GridView para se mostrar os dados da pesquisa.

Minhas dúvidas são:

1. Qual a diferença entre as duas ?
2. Em qual ocasião usar cada uma ?
3. Uma é melhor do que a outra ? Ou as duas são boas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu vejo o grid como uma lista tabulada de dados que não falam tudo sobre si - geralmente exige um cabeçalho (um form com os dados do pai destes registros) e um sumário.

Já o listview eu vejo como uma lista de objetos mais completos (não necessariamente com mais informação - talvez justamente o contrário), podendo esta lista ter visualizações diferentes conforme as informações sobre estes objetos que se deseja ter em destaque naquele momento.

## Exemplo: uma lista de arquivos em uma pasta do Windows

### Objetivo: uma visão geral da pasta

Se o seu objetivo é ter uma idéia da quantidade de arquivos e espaço ocupado por estes arquivos, você provavelmente iria querer listá-los em um grid, vendo no cabeçalho o caminho da pasta e no sumário a quantidade de arquivos e o espaço total ocupado.

O grid com a lista de arquivos neste caso tem uma função secundária de oferecer uma visão geral dos arquivos que estão ali.

### Objetivo: uma análise dos arquivos que estão na pasta

Agora, seu objetivo também pode ser os arquivos em si.

Você pode estar querendo entender coisas do tipo: esta pasta está mais para documentos de trabalho ou da faculdade? Que tipos de arquivos eu tenho aqui? As imagens que estão aqui são particulares?

Neste caso você provavelmente vai querer listar os arquivos em um listview, com ícones grandes que revelem o tipo e eventualmente um pouco sobre o conteúdo, bem como o nome do arquivo, e eventualmente você vai querer mais detalhes sobre um arquivo em particular e vai clicar sobre ele para ver o tamanho e a data de criação sem ter que navegar para outro formulário.

## Conclusão

No primeiro caso o foco está no todo, e a lista é só uma parte deste todo; então usamos grid.

No segundo caso o foco está no item, e a lista permite alternarmos entre diferentes visões e revela muito sobre cada item não apenas de maneira tabulada mas também com as informações dispostas no próprio item; então usamos listview.

Comment: então, digamos que eu tenha um cadastro de alunos, por exemplo. E neste cadastro tenho informações do tipo: ID, nome, nome do pai, nome da mãe, nome do responsável, série,ano. E eu tivesse uma outra tabela com os registros de suas(do aluno) ocorrências. Qual dos dois tipos seria a melhor de usar ?

Comment: Depende de qual é o foco desta interação em particular. O meu exemplo sugere ora grid e ora listview para o mesmo tipo de registros (arquivos). Então não é o tipo que determina o que usar. Digamos que um orientador vai dividir os alunos em turmas conforme o perfil de cada aluno - o foco está no item (o aluno). Digamos que você está vendo os dados de uma turma, a qual tem professor, calendário, sala e alunos - o foco não está nos itens e os alunos estarão em um grid. Além do foco, conta também a interação que você quer oferecer - se ela pode ser a mais simples possível, vá de grid em 1º lugar.

Comment: No Grid, tem como dar dois cliques na linha também ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Tem sim. Se você tiver problemas ao tentar implementar pode fazer novas perguntas.

Comment: Aah, beleza então. Valeu pela resposta !

Answer (score 6):

## Qual a diferença entre as duas?

[`ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) é um componente mais completo, com maior possibilidade de customizações e suporte a ordenação nativa. [`GridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) é um componente mais simples, mais rápido de usar e que demanda menos configuração.

Ambos têm:

- Paginação;
- Edição;
- Seleção;
- Sistema de Templates (`GridView` é mais limitado).

`ListView` tem a mais:

- Ordenação nativa;
- Agrupamento de ítens;
- Extensibilidade de layout aprimorada.

## Em qual ocasião usar cada uma?

Use `GridView` para a maioria das tabelas, que não demanda muita configuração e exige menos processamento na hora de ser gerada.

Use `ListView` para uma visão sofisticada da sua origem de dados, ou com exigência mais específica de layout.

## Uma é melhor que a outra? Ou as duas são boas?

Cada uma atende a um tipo de necessidade. Mensurar isso fica a cargo do programador.